# pl/sql collections limitations - in comparision to java collections

Tags: oracle, collections, plsql

Question regarding pl/sql collections:

I'm generating frequency distribution table for salary data for the hr employees table as below:

1. I'm creating a table type `class_intervals` which holds low frequency ,high frequency and table containing `emp_recs` for `type emp_recs_tb`.

Now for inserting into the `class_intervals` I have to get the corresponding range entry generated above from the `class_intervals`.

How shall I do that?

In java we have HashTable where life is easy as I can query the hash table to get the key. How shall I achieve the same in pl/sql.

Also I'm restrained most of the times because I can't use `index of` for any objects as it is constraining me for pls_integer.

Please add your thoughts.

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE Hr_stat_ci
AS

  CURSOR emp_cur IS
    SELECT first_name,
           salary
    FROM   employees;

  emps            emp_cur%ROWTYPE;
  min_sal         NUMBER(8, 2);
  count_sals      NUMBER;
  max_sal         NUMBER(8, 2);
  avg_sal         NUMBER(8, 2);
  sal_range       NUMBER(8, 2);

  TYPE emp_rec_t IS RECORD (
    emp_name employees.first_name%TYPE,
    emp_sal employees.salary%TYPE);
  emp_record      EMP_REC_T;

  TYPE emp_recs_tb
    IS TABLE OF EMP_REC_T INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

  TYPE ci_rec_t IS RECORD (
    ci_low NUMBER(8, 2),
    ci_high NUMBER(10, 2),
    employee EMP_REC_T);
  class_interval  CI_REC_T;

  TYPE ci_table_tb
    IS TABLE OF CI_REC_T INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  class_intervals CI_TABLE_TB;

  i               NUMBER := 1;
BEGIN
    SELECT Min(salary),
           Max(salary),
           Avg(salary),
           Count(salary)
    INTO   min_sal, max_sal, avg_sal, count_sals
    FROM   employees;

    sal_range := max_sal - min_sal / count_sals;

    dbms_output.Put_line('employee details');

    FOR i IN 1..count_sals LOOP
        class_interval.ci_low := min_sal;

        class_interval.ci_high := min_sal + sal_range;

        min_sal := class_interval.ci_high;

        Class_intervals(i) := class_interval;
    END LOOP;

END hr_stat_ci;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
 TYPE <your_array> IS TABLE OF <your base type> INDEX BY VARCHAR2(32767);
```

which is enough to hold hash string up to 32 K length as an index. To loop this collection you need to to use first- while not last -next loop.